# .NET Authorization. Does the order or allow and deny elements matter?

Tags: .net, authorization, asp.net-authorization

I am curious whether the order in which you supply the `<allow>` and `<deny>` elements in the  element does matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the order matters. This page describes the basic principles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx. As per the page, a list of authorization rules is built up from the hierarchy of config files and then the first match wins.

This SO question has a nice example: [ASP.NET Forms Auth Allowing access to specific file in subdirectory when all others should be denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938891/asp-net-forms-auth-allowing-access-to-specific-file-in-subdirectory-when-all-oth)