# asp.net Authorization rules not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, authorization

There are two users;

admin with `systemAdmin` role and not `powerUser` role

powerUser with `powerUser` role and not `systemAdmin` role

I have the following config in Web.config file located in Project\SystemAdmin directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--Test Result: admin can access, powerUser is denied-->
  <location path="TestPowerUser.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="powerUser"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <!--Test Result: admin can access, powerUser is denied-->
  <location path="TestPowerUserDisallowSysAdmin.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="powerUser"/>
        <deny roles="systemAdmin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <!--Test Result: admin is denied, powerUser is denied-->
  <location path="TestDisallowAll.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <!--Test Result: admin can access, powerUser is denied for all other pages in directory-->
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="systemAdmin"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

When testing with admin user with `systemAdmin` role;

`TestPowerUser.aspx` can be viewed (**expected**)

`TestPowerUserDisallowSysAdmin.aspx` can be viewed (**unexpected**)

`TestDisallowAll.aspx` cannot be viewed (**expected**)

All other pages within directory can be viewed (**expected**)

---

When testing with powerUser user with `powerUser` role;

`TestPowerUser.aspx` cannot be viewed (**unexpected**)

`TestPowerUserDisallowSysAdmin.aspx` cannot be viewed (**unexpected**)

`TestDisallowAll.aspx` cannot be viewed (**expected**)

All other pages within directory cannot be viewed (**expected**)

---

What can I be doing wrong? I am new to asp.net development and will update with any other required details that may be asked.

---

EDIT: I tried the below answered question, still not working as expected.

[ASP.NET Forms Auth Allowing access to specific file in subdirectory when all others should be denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938891/asp-net-forms-auth-allowing-access-to-specific-file-in-subdirectory-when-all-oth?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is due to the file name extensions. There needs to be two location tags per file, one with and one without the file name extension. So for the `TestPowerUser.aspx` file, the location tags should be as following:

```
<location path="TestPowerUser.aspx"> <!--note the inclusion of the extension-->
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="powerUser"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="TestPowerUser"> <!--note the omission of the extension-->
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="powerUser"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

The page-specific authorization works only when both location tags exist.